# Adding custom classes to Views Filters (view-filters) and Content (div.view-contents)

Tags: views, bootstrapping

I'm using a theme that includes bootstrap. I'd like to inject class `one_third` into `<div class="view-filters">` and `two_third last` to `<div class="view-content">`. Is there a way to do so from any theme `theme_preprocess_area`?

I know I could accomplish using javascript (selecting `div.view-filters` and `addClass()`), but I think it would be most prudent to handle in perhaps the preprocessing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views provides a lot of .tpl files for doing just this. They are found in the `/theme` folder of the `views` module folder. The one you want is `views-view.tpl.php`

Simply copy `views-view.tpl.php` into your theme's templates folder and edit ~ line 43 to include your bootstrap classes and whatever other markup you require ;)